# Need node.js and dotnet sdk in same windows docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, .net-core, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I have the following dockerfile for Windows, which fails to install node.js because `msiexec` is not a recognized command...

```yaml
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

#####################################################
# I NEED NODE.JS WITHIN THE SAME LAYER AS DOTNET SDK.
RUN curl -o nodejs.msi https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.16.0/node-v14.16.0-x86.msi
RUN msiexec /i nodejs.msi /quiet /qn /norestart
#####################################################

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["NetWithAngular/NetWithAngular.csproj", "NetWithAngular/"]
RUN dotnet restore "NetWithAngular/NetWithAngular.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/NetWithAngular"
RUN dotnet build "NetWithAngular.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

# ...the rest I've skipped...
```

> 'msiexec' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What is the problem here?  Why is this not working?  I also discovered that a similar attempt to use `powershell` gets the exact same error.  So this is a Windows image without `msiexec` and `powershell`? Huh? Anyway...

Adding another "stage" in the dockerfile, which already has node.js, is not the solution I need.  This is because the dotnet `NetWithAngular.csproj` build is integrated with an Angular SPA and kicks-off "npm build".  In other words, I need the dotnet sdk and node / npm in the *same* layer.
How do I install node.js, when `msiexec` is not availabe?  For that matter, **how on earth** is `msiexec` and `powershell` not available?

#### Update

I have discovered that I can circumvent this problem if I change the base image to:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022
```

With this image, both `msiexec` and `powershell` work.  However, this doesn't fully answer my question.  Why is neither `msiexec` nor `powershell` available with the original base image?  Indeed, someone in the comments says that they have successfully executed `msiexec` using the exact same base image.

Answer (score 1):

```
RUN apt-get update -yq &&  \
  apt-get upgrade -yq &&   \
  apt-get install -yq curl

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential
```

Comment: When I use your `RUN apt-get update...` command, I get `'apt-get' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.  To be clear, this is a dockerfile build for Windows.

Comment: I used this exact container to a customer of mine to install node npm also, checked again to see if i'm wrong and for me it works.